# Passing a method as an argument so that the method can be called later?

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a library with some methods, and during certain errors I want it to call a method as defined by the caller. This method must return a bool. What I mean is:

```
Sock sock = new Sock();
sock.OnSpecificError(theMethodToCall);
```

And then when the error happens, sock should first check to see if OnSpecificError has been set. If it has, it should run it. If the method returns false or if OnSepcificError hasn't been set, it should throw an exception.

This seems like the sort of thing that delegates are designed for, but for whatever reason I can't seem to get my mind around what those are actually doing, as in, what is being passed around and how I'd run it later. My current method of handling this is stupid and cumbersome, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
Let me clarify a bit. sock.OnSpecificError(method) is used to simply pass sock a method, which it will store, but not run. The idea is then that later one, while sock is running some other methods, if the error pops up, it should run that method. I want to keep the method for use later, and then run it if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to start with delegates is by using pre-defined ones. For example, a delegate that takes no arguments and returns a `bool` would be `Func<bool>`. A delegate that takes a `string` and an `int`, and returns a `bool` would be `Func<string,int,bool>`, and so on.

You define your method like this:

```
void OnSpecificError(Func<bool> errorCheck) {
    // Do your stuff...
    var gotErrors = errorCheck();
    if (gotErrors) {
        // Do something about it
    }
}
```

You can now call `OnSpecificError` like this:

```
sock.OnSpecificError(CheckForErrors);

private bool CheckForErrors() {
    return errorCode.Equals("YES");
}
```

You can also use *lambdas* to inline small methods, like this:

```
sock.OnSpecificError(() => errorCode.Equals("YES"));
```

Comment: Okay, I think I get this, let me try out a test to be sure I've got it. So Func<> is a predefined delegate? What exactly does <> signify in the world of C#? I've never been able to get a good answer, since google cringes when I try to google <>

Comment: Actually no, this isn't what I'm looking for. Take a look at the edit I made to my answer, I tried to clarify.

Comment: @cost `<>` is a place for *generic arguments*. `Func<>` is a family of predefined generic delegate types. You can expand it by providing one or more type arguments to indicate parameter types and return type of the delegate.

Comment: The <> are for listing generic type arguments. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk36dx2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx for some explanation.

Comment: @cost You can store a delegate in an instance variable instead of calling it, that would not be a problem. You can then call that delegate when the time is right. However, for the error reporting purposes that you described in your edit, it would be best to use *events*. [Here is a short tutorial from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) explaining how to use events, and providing an easy to follow example.

Comment: Would events be good in this case though? I have some experience with them, but the idea here is that the library is handling some socket operations, but in the event of crippling errors, like a disconnect which it can't fix, there should be some pop up like "check your connection," etc. So would I just hand my library an event instead, and say when this stuff happens, throw the event? It needs to be able to get a return value too. The returned bool is there so the library can know that you've reconnected or not. In the event of not, it has to throw that exception.

Comment: @cost You are right, since return values are required, events are not going to work in your case; `Func<boo>` is a better choice.